# remote gdb symbol table not loaded

Tags: c, linux, gdbserver

I am trying to start remote gdb session. Here is what I did so far .

```
on target m/c.

$ > gdbserver :5555 --attach process_pid

on host from which I need to connect to 

$HOST > gdb
gdb > target remote target_ip:5555
gdb >
```

but after this the I am not able to insert any breakpoints, It says breakpoint is pending (symbol table not loaded).
but If I do continue , my program crashes.

I searched on the web but I couldnt find anything on this. 
I will really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you compile your application using the `-g` flag? [More info](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html)

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you posted the exact output of the error.